# Why can't I access public profile information?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

When I send an API call such as this:

```
$getinfo = $facebook->api('/100005254861029?fields=name,education,email,gender,work,website,locale,currency,birthday');
```

All I get back is name, gender, locale and id even though fields such as email, work, website and education are all publicly available on the profile (for testing purposes).

Does the API not allow you to access information from people you are not friends with, even if it is Public and therefore accessible by going on their page?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have specific extended permissions to get those fields.

By default you can get only fields listed here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/

Read more at 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/
and 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/

Comment: The first link has a list of what's available and the last entry is "Other public information" which Facebook describes as information you choose to make public (using the privacy settings).

By extended persmissions do you mean you would explicitly need to request permissions from the owner of the profile you are looking to take information from?

Comment: yes, or you can also use extended permission with friend_ prefix. as i remember it should work also. But you will need to have valid access_token with required permission to do so

Comment: I want to be able to output the same information a stranger can access by viewing the profile, is this not possible?

Comment: no, i dont think so, application is restricted by whitelisted fields and it doesnt depends on what is public on user profile